# What libraries are there for networking in Windows 98/me/2000/xp ? (except windows sockets)

Tags: c++, windows, hook

I'm trying to hook into an application's networking layer (NFS: Underground 2), but it doesn't use wsock32.dll. Yet it does have networking abilities. They are mostly broken on windows 7/8 so I want to hook and rewrite them.. to fix most of the issues on playing on a LAN connection.

But how can I determine the networking functions if I inject a DLL made in C++?

What networking functions are there in windows to use in C++? I have detemrined the application is compiled using MSVC++ 2005 compiler

I have tried looking into what dll's it loads but only dinput, dsound, d3d9, nvidia graphics dll's and the nt system dll.

Comment: Ws2_32 can be used for sockets as well.

Comment: hmm, lots of googling later: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc958787.aspx then I see it's mswsock.dll hmm,